# Chrome Extension edit source file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a chrome extension that is installed via "Load unpacked extension," and I am trying to get it to delete itself or at least change its source code when a function is called. I have the `chrome.management.uninstallSelf` down, but I also need the source files for it to become changed/gone. Basically, I need the chrome extension to open the local file where its source is located and then delete/change some of the files inside it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I need the chrome extension to open the local file where its source is located and then delete/change some of the files inside it. Is there any way to do this?

No, this isn't normally* possible.

Chrome extensions have only read-only access to their own files (via `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry` or requests to `chrome-extension://`), and no access at all to the rest of the filesystem.

---

* All bets are off if you have a [Native Host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) module though. It can do whatever, but would greatly complicate installation.

Comment: I thought it would be a long shot... Oh well. Thanks anyway!